# Ubuntu init script failed - trying to find out more detail about the error

Tags: ubuntu, boot, upstart, active-directory

My `/var/log/boot.log` shows this under Ubuntu 14.04:

```
 ... 
 * Starting servicename <br>
chown: invalid user: ‘username’<br>
No passwd entry for user 'username'<br>
 * Starting ...<br>
 ...
```

The init script `/etc/init.d/servicename` does not contain such `chown` command.

How can I found out, where this `chown` comes from?

Comment: What does `/var/log/syslog` reveal? Also what services are around this one? Those will help to narrow focus on which service this ultimately is.

Comment: syslog does display nothing about this service :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service `servicename` needs a user from Active Directory using [PBIS](http://www.beyondtrust.com/Resources/OpenSourceDocumentation/) (formerly Likewise Open). By the way, PBIS stands for PowerBroker Identity Services.

So the PBIS service has to be fully up. After that the service can start with that user. If Jenkins's init script is the very last one, it worked.

**NOTE:** So, be careful when services depend on other services being started by init.